# Reset cumulative summation whenever there is zero in the vector using R

Tags: r

I need to reset the cumulative summation whenever there is zero in the vector using R. E.g. Input c(0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1) I want the output as 0,1,0,0,0,1,2,3,0,1,2. I checked multiple answers which answer resetting of sequence using functions, but those solutions did not work here.

[Numeric sequence with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32965823/numeric-sequence-with-condition),
[Create counter with multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487109/create-counter-with-multiple-variables),
[Comp. Efficent way of resetting sequence if condition met ( R )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082085/comp-efficent-way-of-resetting-sequence-if-condition-met-r) are some which I referred. 
I tried different combinations of cumsum, ave and getanID but can't seem to get the output I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

perhaps something like this:

```
vec <- c(0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1)
library(data.table)
as.numeric(unlist(by(vec, rleid(vec), cumsum))) #or as in Maurits Evers answer `unname`, or `unlist(..., use.names = F)` instead of `as.numeric`
#output
 0 1 0 0 0 1 2 3 0 1 2
```

rleid makes a run-length type id column:

```
rleid(vec)
#output
1 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 6 6
```

this is then used as a grouping variable

EDIT: as per suggestion of @digEmAll:

Note that this works only if vec contains only 0 and 1. To make it more generic you should use

`rleid(vec > 0)`

Comment: Nice. I would include the output of `rleid(vec)` in the answer, to facilitate the understanding.

Comment: Note that this works only if vec contains only 0 and 1. To make it more generic you should use `rleid(vec > 0)`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R solution using `split`:

```
v <- c(0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1)
unname(unlist(lapply(split(v, cumsum(c(0, diff(v) != 0))), cumsum)))
# [1] 0 1 0 0 0 1 2 3 0 1 2
```

The idea is to split the vector into chunks based on `0`s, and then calculate the `cumsum` per chunk.

Instead of `unname(unlist(...))` you can also use `unlist(..., use.names = F)`.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution using `ave` and `rle`:

```
ave(v,inverse.rle(with(rle(v>0),list(values=seq_along(values),lengths=lengths))),FUN=cumsum)
>
[1] 0 1 0 0 0 1 2 3 0 1 2
```

Note that :

```
inverse.rle(with(rle(v>0),list(values=seq_along(values),lengths=lengths))
```

is equal to :

```
data.table::rleid(v>0)
```

and thay return the "ids" of the batches of consecutive zero/non-zero elements  of v :

```
[1] 1 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 6 6
```